# How can I render multiple modelsummary calls to my pdf?

Tags: r, quarto, modelsummary

Suppose I have many models I would like to summarize in separate tables.  One way to do this would be to write out each model in a `modelsummary` call as follows

```r
library(modelsummary)
fit_1 <- lm(vs ~ am, data=mtcars)
fit_2 <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)


modelsummary(
  models = list('First Model' = fit_1),
    statistic = c(
    'Std.Error' = 'std.error', 
    'P val' = 'p.value', 
    'Lower' = 'conf.low',
    'Upper' = 'conf.high'),
  gof_map = NA,
  shape= term ~ statistic
)


modelsummary(
  models = list('Second Model' = fit_2),
    statistic = c(
    'Std.Error' = 'std.error', 
    'P val' = 'p.value', 
    'Lower' = 'conf.low',
    'Upper' = 'conf.high'),
  gof_map = NA,
  shape= term ~ statistic
)
```

When I render my pdf using quarto, this produces two model summaries as expected.  However, one can imagine that this gets repetitive for more than a few models, especially if I would like to change the tables slightly.  Hence, I can write a function to make these tables

```r
models<- list(
  'First Model'=fit_1,
  'Secpond Model' = fit_2

)

do_modelsummary <- function(model, model_name){
  
  mod <- list(model)
  names(mod) <- model_name
  
  modelsummary(
  models = mod,
    statistic = c(
    'Std.Error' = 'std.error', 
    'P val' = 'p.value', 
    'Lower' = 'conf.low',
    'Upper' = 'conf.high'),
  gof_map = NA,
  shape= term ~ statistic
)
  
}
```

I can then loop through the list as follows

```r
for(i in length(models)) {
  
  fit <- models[[i]]
  nm <- names(models)[[i]] 
  do_modelsummary(fit, nm)
  
}
```

This *does not* display the table upon rendering the pdf. Additionally, `purrr::imap` -- which does this more succinctly -- errors when attempting to render the pdf.

```
purrr::imap(models, do_modelsummary)

ERROR: 
compilation failed- error
File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> Untitled.tex
                 

see Untitled.log for more information.
```

If I want to display multiple model summaries individually and render to pdf, what is the preferred way which is *not* doing each table indivudually.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the key here was setting `results='asis'` in the code chunk in which performs the loop.  Then, the loop and the call to `imap` render the tables.